# combobox binding - show field names in bindingsource

Tags: vb.net, combobox, bindingsource

I am trying to use a bindingsource as the datasource for a combobox. The display and value members of the combobox will be the field names in my bindingsource's datasource.

Currently I use a process of populating a datatable and assigning it to the datasource of the combobox. Because I already have the bindingsource populated with data it would make sense to just set the binding up rather than continue to use this code below:

```
  Dim dtfields As New DataTable
    dtfields = mySqlref.sqlobj.SelectData(String.Format("select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = '{0}' order by ordinal_position", mydata.Table), SqlLibrary.SqlLibrary.SelectType.datatable)

    cboField.DataSource = dtfields
    cboField.ValueMember = "column_name"
    cboField.DisplayMember = "column_name"
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks for reading.

Comment: I am not sure about your question. How is the structure of the bindingSource (how different it is to `dtfields`)? Bear in mind that it might be set directly as `DataSource`. For example: `Dim binding As BindingSource = New BindingSource()  binding.DataSource = dtfields   cboField.DataSource = binding`

Comment: The bindingsource contains all data from one table in my database (numerous rows, about 17 fields). dtFields contains only names of fields in this table. Because bindingsource already has the data which contains all field names for me I want to find some way to getEnumerator or toList those fieldnames so I can bind it to my combobox. Make sense?

Comment: Yes, sure. But just saying BindingSource does not make any sense; it behaves as a mere container (or a DataTable, for example; as shown in my example). The combobox is expecting a 1D DataSource, you can either select the exact column you want from a 2D dataset (as you are doing with the DataTable) or create a 1D collection from the whole data. But you have to say the exact conditions (input dataset and expected 1D collection) in order to get help; what you are saying and the code you posted does not provide any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort of answer I was looking for here was:

**if your fieldnames are already in your bindingsource then you can use linq to create an array of those fieldnames instead of using a seperate query to call the database for field names**

Here's the code I ended up using:

```
 Dim arraynames = (From x As DataColumn In mydata.Table.Columns Select x.ColumnName).ToArray()
    cboField.DataSource = arraynames
```

in this example "mydata" is a dataview. It is the object upon which my binding source is created. I extract column names into an array using the datatable object inside that dataview.